# Visualizing the uniqueness of fields in identifying other fields in a data set

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a data visualization question. 
My data looks like this: {int x, int y, string a, string b, ...  }

I want to visualize the ability of {x,y} to uniquely identify {a,b}. 
I.e if x,y are known then there is often 1 and sometimes just a few possible combinations of a,b. I know this is the case in my data but I want to show in a visualization. What is the best approach to do it assuming the number of records is about 5000?

```
Here are a few lines of this data
2320,1190,T,a
3051,1680,i,a
3099,1495,N,v
3395,1475,C,v
3395,1475,C,c
3400,1480,C,a
3405,1615,A,a
3430,1630,1f,a
3440,1480,C1,d
3440,1640,C1,e
3450,1640,u,lk
```

Comment: Can you share the first few lines of your dataset?

Comment: I edited the post to show the data and also the order of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for. From here you could facet out the non-unique entries.

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(file="clipboard", sep=",",             #Read in your data
               header=F, skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$key <- with(df, paste0(V1, V2))                      #Make Key from {x,y}
Counts <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~key, data = df))         #Get counts for {x,y} pairs

df_merge <- merge(df, Counts, by = "key", all.x =T)        #Merge the Tables by Key
df_merge$Unique <- ifelse(df_merge$Freq == 1, "Yes", "No") #Unique Yes or No

qplot(data = df_merge, x = V1, y = V2, color = Unique, geom = "point") #Plot
```